# VBA for Extracting Data Between 2 Dates From Different Product Sheets to Main sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to Extract Products Sales From Different Sheets depends on DATES( Between Two Dates), In the mainsheet, I have Two Columns : A for Dates; B for Sales Numbers. I'm new to VBA and trying to write code from learnt Youtube Videos, So far I can be able retrieve Only Column A values i.e, Only Dates, But I could not get the Sales values along with the Dates. I'm writing the Code Down here, Could you please check it once and let me know where and what exactly the mistake arise, your Suggestion Could helpful to me. Thank you in Advance. :)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet, Psh As String, x As Date, y As Date
Sheet8.Columns("A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Psh = Me.Shproducts ' Shproducts is Command Button Name
Set sh = Worksheets(Psh)
 x = CDate(Me.TextBox1) ' Start Date
 y = CDate(Me.TextBox2) ' End Date

Dim i As Long, Myrange As Range, Lastrow As Long


For i = 3 To sh.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


If sh.Cells(i, 1) >= x And sh.Cells(i, 1) <= y Then
Sheet8.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = sh.Cells(i, 1)
Sheet8.Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = sh.Cells(i, 2)

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tested it, but you might want to do something like this. so this is based on your code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim sh As Worksheet, Psh As String, x As Date, y As Date
  Dim i As Long, Myrange As Range, Lastrow As Long
  Dim destinationRange As Range, c As Range, sourceRange As Range
  Dim counter As Long
  Dim currentDate As Date, currentSales As Double

  Sheet8.Columns("A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

  Psh = Me.Shproducts ' Shproducts is Command Button Name
  Set sh = Worksheets(Psh)
  x = CDate(Me.TextBox1) ' Start Date
  y = CDate(Me.TextBox2) ' End Date

  Set destinationRange = Sheet8.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 
  Set sourceRange = Range(sh.Range("F3"), sh.Range("F3").End(xlDown))

  For Each c In sourceRange
    currentDate = c.Value
    currentSales = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
    If currentDate >= x And currentDate <= y Then
      destinationRange.Offset(counter, 0).Value = currentDate
      destinationRange.Offset(counter, 1).Value = currentSales
      counter = counter + 1
    End If
  Next i

End Sub
```